# A decreasing sequence, difference by convergent sequence of which is increasing, is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence in that $$a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots.$$
Suppose also that $\{a_n-\frac1n\}$ is a monotonically incereasing sequence.
Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

**My trial** : It is a *well known fact* that a decreasing sequence, which is bounded below, is convergent.
So it is enough to prove that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded below.
Since
$a_1-1\le a_n-\frac1n$ for all $n$, $$a_n\ge a_1-1+\frac1n\gt a_1-1$$
and $\{a_n\}$ is bounded below.

I think my proof is valid.
But is there an alternative way that doesn't use the *well known fact*?

Comment: If you want to prove convergence without knowing the limit then you need *some* form of the completeness axiom (monotone convergence theorem, least-upper-bound-property, convergence of Cauchy sequences) and these are all equivalent ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property#Logical_status)).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I'm understanding what you're saying. Is the *monotone convergence theorem* equal to my *well known fact*? I'm confused with the theorem in the Lebesgue theory.

Comment: @MartinR I like least-upper-bound property, since I first encountered this kind of argument in my sophomore, in analysis class (baby Rudin). So you're saying that I can prove my question by the least-upper-bound property, right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that the sequence is Cauchy directly. Fix $n$ and let $m > n$. Then $a_m \leq a_n$ and $a_n - \frac{1}{n} \leq a_m - \frac{1}{m}$ by virtue of the $(a_n)$ being monotonically decreasing, and $(a_n - 1/n)$ being monotonically increasing. This results in the inequality
$$a_m - \frac{1}{n} \leq a_n - \frac{1}{n} \leq a_m - \frac{1}{m}.$$
If you subtract $a_m-\frac{1}{n}$ from the inequality, you obtain
$$0 \leq a_n - a_m \leq \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \leq \frac{1}{n}.$$
This is what you need to prove that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. (For $\epsilon > 0,$ pick $n$ such that $1/n < \epsilon...$)

Comment: Great. So the sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent. So you're using the fact that every Cauchy sequence is convergent.